# DELL OpenManage 7.3 on ESXi5.1

Tags: vmware-esxi, nagios, dell, dell-openmanage

I installed Dell OpenManage 7.3 VIB on ESXi5.1 host. I assumed that VIB will load all DELL specific MIBs into OS. I enabled snmpd on that host as well, but when I am doing "snmpwalk" or "snmpget" I do not get information on Dell specific OIDs

The source of the VIB:

[DELL OpenManage 7.3 VIB](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails/Product/poweredge-r820?driverId=6C7D3&osCode=XI51&fileId=3230258625&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SM)

The output i get:

```
nmpget -v2c -c public myesxi.domain.com 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.1.300.10.1.8.1

SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.1.300.10.1.8.1 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

I do get OIDs from VMWare stack, but not the Dell ones.
Eventually I want to use nagios plugin "check_openmanage" but it apparently gives me an error as it cannot query Dell OID's

Am I missing something?

EDIT: I see the package is installed:

```
# esxcli software vib list | grep -i "OpenManage"
OpenManage                     7.3-0000                              Dell      PartnerSupported  2013-08-21
```

Comment: Do you have OMSA installed somewhere else that you can point at that box to see if the VIB actually installed in ESXi?

Comment: # esxcli software vib list | grep -i "OpenManage"
OpenManage                     7.3-0000                              Dell      PartnerSupported  2013-08-21

Comment: I could've *sworn* this worked. Spoke with the author, he says it never did, but it might be possible in the future. Instead, he says the iDRAC (v7 and up) has some SNMP support that can be used for monitoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I don't think you can.](http://en.community.dell.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-20-07-10-85/How-to-setup-and-configure-ESXi-5-for-OME.pdf) It says  that the only SNMP support is for sending traps, not for querying.

> This configuration is only for sending SNMP traps to OpenManage Essentials. SNMP is not used for discovery. WS-MAN is the only protocol ESXi 5 supports.

Your monitoring tool will need to speak WS-MAN - Dell OME is one such tool. I am too lazy to look up Nagios' support for WS-MAN right now.

The [documentation for check_openmanage](http://folk.uio.no/trondham/software/check_openmanage.html#is-vmware-esxi-supported) seems to agree with me.

Comment: Because OMSA used to support SNMP? Maybe it still does on non-ESXi platforms like Windows and Linux? I dunno - read the docs.

Comment: How come then this check exists and quite popular?http://folk.uio.no/trondham/software/check_openmanage.html#download Would not make any sense to have it.

Comment: Ok. let me verify it. You might be right.

Comment: Dude - seriously. Read the docs for the products in question.  http://folk.uio.no/trondham/software/check_openmanage.html#is-vmware-esxi-supported

Comment: Oh nice, I did not get to that point -))). Thanks

Comment: Do you know is there a way at all to use SNMP on ESXi, besides their standard loaded MIBs?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking at this point. You said you could query VMware OIDs, and you now know that you can't query Dell OIDs since they're not supported using the OpenManage VIB. That's the whole story.

Comment: It seems that would be the only way which is not supported. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may be able to query the DRAC via SNMP for some hardware health

Comment: Or, if you have a big enough Dell footprint, install and configure OME. It's generally a good idea to run the vendor-specific server infrastructure tools, even if you already have a monitoring solution.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, SNMP hardware polling doesn't work with OMSA on ESXi so you can't use check_openmanage, but since  your goal is hardware monitoring, you might look at  [check_esxi_hardware.py](http://www.claudiokuenzler.com/nagios-plugins/check_esxi_hardware.php) plugin (for Dell, HP, IBM).  It works exactly as advertised on ESXi 5.1 with OMSA 7.3 and has very similar output to check_openmanage.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the 7.3 VIB from your windows workstation you are going to want this,
courtesy of Dell India(only Dell-site who would list it),
**OpenManage Server Administrator Version 7.3**
http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER01679890M/1/OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-WIN-7.3.0-350_A00.exe