# Monitor Dell hardware on ESXi 5.1 using check_esxi_hardware on Centreon

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-openmanage, centreon

I installed Dell OpenManage on ESXi5.1 Host, which I'd like to monitor through Centreon. Since check_openmanage plugin is not to be used with ESXi (according to [that post](https://serverfault.com/questions/532955/dell-openmanage-7-3-on-esxi5-1) : [DELL OpenManage 7.3 on ESXi5.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/532955/dell-openmanage-7-3-on-esxi5-1) and to my own experience), I installed the [check_esxi_hardware](http://www.claudiokuenzler.com/nagios-plugins/check_esxi_hardware.php) plugin instead.

I'd like to know if it has check_openmanage features, such as *showing only the processor's temperature*.

For now I use `./check_esxi_hardware.py -H hostname -U user -P password --perfdata` and I get everything in a block : `OK - Server: Dell Inc. PowerEdge R520 s/n: 3GHPV02 System BIOS: 2.1.2 2014-01-20|P1Pow_0_System_Board_1_Pwr_Consumption=154;588;644 P2Vol_0_Power_Supply_1_Voltage_1=230;0;0 P2Vol_1_Power_Supply_2_Voltage_2=230;0;0 P3Cur_0_Power_Supply_1_Current_1=0.4;0;0 P3Cur_1_Power_Supply_2_Current_2=0.4;0;0 P4Tem_0_Processor_1_Temp=48;0;0 P4Tem_1_Processor_2_Temp=42;0;0 P4Tem_2_System_Board_1_Inlet_Temp=24;42;47 ...`

If it is possible to have these by pieces I wish to use the instructions to make Centreon commands (or Nagios, they're pretty alike).

Thank you :)

Comment: I eventually made my own plugin to select the interesting pieces of information (Temperature here) and monitor it via Centreon, using basic shell scripting. (Ask me if you need exactly this kind of script, but it's not something amazing ;) )

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion its best to do check all the runtime health sensors using the vmware sdk and notify of the sensors that don't have a green state. This is (among other stuff) exactly what the [check_vmware_api by op5](https://kb.op5.com/display/HOWTOs/Monitoring+VMware+ESX,+ESXi,+vSphere+and+vCenter+Server) does using the '-l runtime -s health' switches.

```
$ ./check_vmware_api -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u user -p pwd -l runtime -s health
CHECK_ESX.PL OK - All 217 health checks are Green
```